# Parallelize recursive deletion with find

Tags: find, recursive, parallelism, multiprocessor

I want to recursively delete all files that end with `.in`. This is taking a long time, and I have many cores available, so I would like to parallelize this process. From [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/193319/a-better-unix-find-with-parallel-processing), it looks like it's possible to use `xargs` or `make` to parallelize `find`. Is this application of find possible to parallelize?

Here is my current serial command:

```
find . -name "*.in" -type f -delete
```

Comment: This is very likely I/O bound, and not CPU bound, so adding more cores probably won't help. If your `find` spans several harddisks, just do a `find` for each one.

Comment: Are you sure it is deleting is slow and not recursive find? It can be, especially when it must do a lot of `stat()` calls on an aged filesystem on a HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing `-delete` with `-print` (which is the default) and piping
into GNU parallel should mostly do it:

```
find . -name '*.in' -type f | parallel rm --
```

This will run one job per core; use `-j N` to use `N` parallel jobs
instead.

It's not completely obvious that this will run much faster than
deleting in sequence, since deleting is probably more I/O- than
CPU-bound, but it would be interesting to test out.

(I said "mostly do it" because the two commands are not fully
equivalent; for example, the `parallel` version will not do the right
thing if some of your input paths include newline characters.)

Comment: I wonder if anyone has done a test to see if it's any faster?

Comment: @DmytroLysak I don't think so. It would make a very nice addition to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `find . -name "*.in" -type f -delete` with `find . -name '*.in' -type f | parallel rm --` (or its more correct equivalent with `find -print0` + `parallel -0` (or `xargs -r0 -P10 -n1`)) might not always be a good option.

```bash
$ parallel -X touch {}.testfile ::: {00000..99999}
$ ls | wc -l
100000
$ time find . -name '*.testfile' -type f | parallel -j10 rm --

real    20m58.470s
user    11m30.553s
sys     58m15.265s
```

```bash
$ parallel -X touch {}.testfile ::: {00000..99999}
$ ls | wc -l
100000
$ time find . -name '*.testfile' -type f -delete

real    3m57.199s
user    0m0.973s
sys     0m37.356s
```

As you can see here **the sequential version is much faster**. As others indicated correctly the **I/O bound is** the **limiting** factor (CPU, disk and memory utilisation was very low) and parallelisation just adds some overhead (in the simple case).

---

Tweaking the parallelisation options might get you similar or better results. One way to start is the options described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-speeding-up-fast-jobs).

This one is a bit cheated (here I don't `find` the files but assume I know the names) *but still slower* than the sequential one:

```bash
$ time seq -f 'rm %04g.testfile' 00000 99999 | parallel --pipe sh

real    8m9.800s
user    2m54.668s
sys     0m57.027s
```

Comment: The main problem with those approaches is that it runs one `rm`, each in its own new process, each loading and initialising the executable for each file which is many orders of magnitude more work than what `find -delete` does. Calling `rm` with more than one file, like with `-n 200` with  GNU `xargs` would likely hugely help.